# Right click inspect element on IE11 developer tools always to to top of HTML

Tags: angular, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools

Currently, I have an angular app. With IE 11, when I right click any element, it will launch the web developer tool. It will always land on the top of HTML element. I have tested other websites, it seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an angular app. With IE 11, when I right click any element, it
>   will launch the web developer tool. It will always land on the top of
>   HTML element.

Can't reproduce the problem on my side, I have tried to create an angular application, it works well on my side. Please check your code, whether you attach the right click function? If possible, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Besides, please try to re-build the angular app and clear the IE browser cache and history, then re-test your code.

If still not working, you could try to [reset the IE browser setting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17441/windows-internet-explorer-change-reset-settings) or re-install the IE browser.

Comment: we have a react app, then embed into angular app. Angular's style overwrite it.

Comment: Can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?